# CSS How to achieve word cloud?

Tags: css, word-cloud

I'm trying to create a word cloud type output with only CSS. Basically, I have a div box and a X number of text elements which need to go inside the box. However, they need to be of different font size. For example, let's say I have this:

```
.box { display: flex; width: 40vw; height: 30vw; overflow: hidden; }
.text1 { font-size: 5vw; }
.text2 { font-size: 4vw; }
.text3 { font-size: 3.5vw; }
.text4 { font-size: 3vw; }
```

I can position the text elements inside the box but I have a few questions regarding the layout. My lack of thorough CSS knowledge prevents me from telling if this is possible at all with just CSS or not:

- How can I avoid collision of the text elements?
- How can I ensure they stay within the boundaries of the box?

Comment: Post a minimal code working snippet that reproduce the issue

Comment: I don't have one and my issue is I don't really know how to do this and if it's possible. Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is this: https://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/279553/362180666/stock-vector-vector-concept-abstract-business-success-marketing-word-cloud-wordcloud-on-background-for-business-362180666.jpg

Comment: you can get some ideas from http://varya.me/en/posts/pseudo-tag-cloud-css/, it is using `:nth-of-type()` pseudoclass

Comment: [This library](https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) uses D3 and is very easy to use to create word clouds.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's not possible to make Word Cloud using CSS only, you need to have Javascript function or lib like [WordCloud2.js](https://github.com/timdream/wordcloud2.js) that handle element positioning.

Demo:
https://timdream.org/wordcloud/#wikipedia:Cloud

References:

- https://github.com/timdream/wordcloud2.js
- https://github.com/timdream/wordcloud